# laravel Backpack, how to auth user

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-backpack

I, i have activate socialite and backpack, after the first step of facebook login i have generate my user in db.

```
    $UserModel = BackpackUser::create(['name' => $userProvider->getName(),
                                           'email' => $userProvider->getEmail(),
                                           'provider' => $provider,
                                           'provider_id' => $userProvider->getId(),
                                           'avatar' => $userProvider->getAvatar(),
                                           'avatar_original' => $userProvider->getAvatar(),
                                           'avatar_original' => $userProvider->avatar_original,
                                           "email_verified_at"=>now()->timestamp,//verifica fatta in quanto arriva dai social
                                           'remember_token' => $userProvider->token,
                                           "password" => Hash::make(Str::random(8)),
                                           "user_type" => "player"
                ]);
```

now , after creation i have authenticate my new user from model BackpacUser

```
Auth::login($UserModel);
```

my check auth tell me

**Auth::check(); = true**

but when i try to access to backpack dashboard , i 'm redirect to login page.

Comment: I think you need to also use the backpack_auth() guard. Take a closer look at Backpack’s LoginController you’re trying to replace - it uses that guard - https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Base/blob/master/src/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

Comment: no, the problem is the backpack\LoginController after Auth::login($UserModel); the app see always not authenticated my user, maybe i have forgot some configuration. I have change it the class in config/auth in 'model' => App\Models\BackpackUser::class, but nothing , not work.

Comment: when backpack logincontroller check in construct if is it present property loginPath, the check is always false and redirect me in login page

Comment: i have tried use in my AuthController Auth::login($UserModel); + backpack_auth();, but nothing, myabe is not compatible with socialite :*(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved, i used backpack_auth()->login($UserModel); and not Auth::login($UserModel); in my AuthController